# Magento email translate tax

Tags: email, magento, translation

I am trying to edit the translation of "Tax" in my New Order Email template.

What did I do?

- show inline template hints and send an order

this shows the tax comes from the file:
frontend/base/default/template/tax/order/tax.phtml

When I hardcode something behind:
__('Tax'); ?>
it shows up. So that means I am SURE that I have to look for the 'Tax' translation

I edited these rule

- "Tax","Tax"

to

- "Tax","VAT"

inside the files:

- Mage_Catalog.csv
- Mage_reports.csv
- mage_Tax.csv
- Mage_adminhtml.csv
- Phoenix_BankPayment.csv
- Mage_Sales.csv
- Mage_Customer.csv
- Mage_checkout.csv

Flushed the translation blocks and Magento Cache. 
But somehow the right translation won't show up..

I even checked the database for the translation, but no entries in there. So I am sure it must be in the CSV files!

Thanks in advance,
Martijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was located in **Idev_OneStepCheckout.csv**
I had to add another Translation rule like:

```
"Tax","VAT"
```

Comment: I still recommend you to use translate.csv (maybe in future projects) because it's easier to have all changes in one place. Even if you want to translate it only for one specific extension, try "Idev_OneStepCheckout::Tax","VAT"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create translate.csv file inside your theme?

app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/locale/languagecode_COUNTRYCODE/translate.csv

For American English it would be en_US (please make sure that you use this language in Admin Panel->System->Configuration->Locale Options)

app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv

And then add new line

“Tax”,"VAT"

After that you need to flush Translations cache.